# financial statement

Tags: financial-literacy, tuition

i'm a student and in my academic financial statement there is the money which i am supposed to pay for the registration and modules fees on the debit side, which is less than the one on the credit side.

Then on the credit side there's this amount that i get from the bursary, and it is more than the one that is on the debit side.

On the last column of the debit side the difference of the two sides and it is written "amount due to you" with a negative sign. I want to know if i still owe some money or i have some left for me.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience with student tuition documents, it sounds like there is money *due to you from the school*.

From your description, I would guess that your statement looks something like this:

**Credits:**

- Bursary loan/grant/scholarship === 10,000

**Debits:**

- Registration  === 3,400
- Lab/Classroom Fees === 600

**Balance:**  === -6,000

If that's the case, remember that this document is from the school's accounting system and so it is registering a negative *from the perspective of the school's finances*.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the previous answer based upon your particular situation.

If the column states something like "Amount Due to you", and is a negative number, then you owe that amount.

Much like the previous poster states that a Balance would be money you owe, and if it was negative then the school owes you the same can be said for the column in question.

If the number was positive, the school would owe you that amount, if negative then you owe them.

Keep in mind you could always post a pic of the document blacking out personal information.